# Symfony 5 - constraints on DateType::class

Tags: php, symfony

I try to figured out how I can add constraint to my DateType field using form builder

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date;

class InscriptionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $builder->add('user_name', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'nom',
            'constraints' => [
                new Length([
                    'min' => 3,
                    'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 2 caractères ou plus'
                ]),
                new Regex([
                    'pattern' => '/^[\wéèêàäâçïöôîûüù\' \-]+$/',
                    'message' => 'La chaîne comporte des caractères non autorisés'
                ]),
                new NotBlank()
            ]
        ])->add('user_birthdate', DateType::class, [
            'label' => 'Date de naissance',
            'placeholder' => [
                'year' => 'Année',
                'month' => 'Mois',
                'day' => 'Jours'
            ],
            'format' => 'ddMMyyyy',
            'constraints' => [
                new Date(),
                new NotBlank()
            ]
        ])
        
    }

}
```

That piece of code render date with 3 select boxes.
I always get this error 'this value should be a string' as I choose value from boxes

How can I use constraint to ensure that date were send is valid like the other field name ?

Comment: since you didn't set the *option* `required` to false, the field will probably already ensure all by itself, that it's a valid date, since it's being converted to a `\Date`. So IMHO you should be able to omit the constraint entry alltogether for the user's birthdate.

Comment: That field is required for my needs. Comment edited because I didn’t understand correctly yours sorry.

Comment: as I mentioned: the DateType form field will try to convert the user input into a date. if that fails, it will most likely produce an error that will be directed at the user.

Comment: I’ll do that hope it’s safe :) thank you